# recreating the dialogue sounds of the 60s

Tags: adr, dialogue, vintage

i am working on a series that is 100% adr. The series is in the style of a 1960s dubbed film and have been asked to process the dialogue so that it reflects those times. . Any suggestions thoughts or links i would welcome. Have tried the kings microphones but i am more interested in sculpting the tone rather than set and forget.

Answer (score 5):

Do you have access to a nagra? you could run the dialog trough tape
to give it that kind of feel

Answer (score 4):

Perry Mason is a great reference point.  It's actually a fantastic case study in the progress of audio recording technology.  You're probably going to want to check out anything from seasons 7-10.  For the time it's probably some of the period's best quality recording, at least that I've seen.

For tone shaping, try the AIR Vintage Filter in PT 8 or 9.  If you can get past the slow load time and the ugly interface, it's really quite fantastic.  Import a section of your reference film and then tone-match from there.

Comment: @g.a.harry... Rockin' Tip!

I've never tried that on Dialog before... always thought of it as a standard filter sweep type effect. It really does add some nice character to Dialog! I'll be using that tip for sure!

Comment: @mrwednesday; I'd recommend throwing an EQ3-7 in after the VF to get it really tight.  I usually boost the Fat and leave the actual filter pretty open.  That way I can get the tape drive and still be able to shape the overall sound as well.  Remember that those old tape machines made it up to *maybe* 6k.  So go hard on the high-end.  I'd love to hear what you come up with.

Answer (score 2):

Some things to experiment with:

Using a ribbon mic to record the dialog.

Re-recording the dialog to optical film (will yield the best results).

Re-recording the dialog to 1/2 inch, 1/4 inch, cassete or VHS tape.

Tape saturation plug-ins.

Speakerphone.

Izotope Vinyl.

Notch EQ.

Adding various optical noise under the dialog.

Comment: Great suggestions.  I've been wanting to experiment with this so I'll try them out and play around.

Answer (score 2):

Limit the upper and lower frequencies, slightly over compress and add some underlying white noise.  The noise interacts with the original signals and generates harmonics.   Then boost the upper mid range to add emphasis, lastly allow the actors to move slightly off mic during the ADR sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Sans Amp works really well

Answer (score 0):

Experiment with the procedure that Mr. Gary Rizo and his team(rerecorder mixer in skywalker) used in "We owned the night". They wanted the 70's sound. So, he first asked the rerecording mixers of that period how they used to process the dialogue back in the days and what part of the process affected the sound. After his research, he inserted in his mixing board the next chain: the outputs of an analogue Nagra( it was used for the dailies) feeding the inputs of a single stripe recorder( it was used for edtining), the outputs of the single stripe recorder feeding the inputs of a fullcoat mag( used for the final mix) and back to the cadenza mixing board( cadenza? I might be wrong about the model of the board). Try also mixing mono.

+1 for the ribbon mic!

When you finish I would love to hear your conclusions.

Best regards

Comment: @Marco I think it's credenza ;)

Answer (score 0):

I will be editing some online episodes very soon and will post links if anyone is interested.
Again, thanks for the replies.

Comment: Congratulations on getting the job! I'm sure it was excited experimenting and being creative at the same time. I'm interested on watching some episodes. 
